# Status bar shows on android when keyboard is visible

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

have full screen app developed for both ios and android using ionic.
I have `<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />` on config.xml and

`if (window.StatusBar) {
    // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
    StatusBar.hide();
    ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
}
// StatusBar.styleDefault();
ionic.Platform.isFullScreen = true;` on app.js. 
On the android device when i click on input text field to type something statusbar shows automatically. We i close the keyboard status bar still remains visible until i close it manually. How can i fix this. Please suggest me. 
Thanks

Comment: What are the versions of Cordova and Ionic?

Comment: Ionic version 1.7.14 & cordova version 6.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the work around solution which i figured out myself.

`if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
         window.addEventListener("native.hidekeyboard", function () { 
         StatusBar.hide();
         window.AndroidFullScreen.immersiveMode(false, false);
           });}`

Put this code on app.js in `$ionicPlatform.ready`. Feel free to reply on this post if you are still having same issue. 
Thanks

Comment: Won't work, since this should fire on "native.keyboardshow". In addition, the statusbar animates out, so it is visible briefly.